# MVC5 and IIS 7.5 Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

I have virtual server where is configured IIS 7.5 to works with ASP.NET MVC.
When I deploy application everything works fine. Only one thing is not working when I run application, maybe I'm wrong but I thought that code is correct.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Subcode").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#MasterId").change(function () {
        if ($("#MasterId").val() != "Select Master Code") {
            var CountryOptions = {};
            CountryOptions.url = "/Audit/FindSubCode";
            CountryOptions.type = "POST";
            CountryOptions.data = JSON.stringify({ master_id: $("#MasterId").val() });
            CountryOptions.datatype = "json";
            CountryOptions.contentType = "application/json";
            CountryOptions.success = function (SubCodeList) {
                $("#Subcode").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < SubCodeList.length; i++) {
                    $("#Subcode").append("<option>" + SubCodeList[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#Subcode").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            CountryOptions.error = function () { alert("Error in Getting SubCodes!!"); };
            $.ajax(CountryOptions);
        }
        else {
            $("#Subcode").empty();
            $("#Subcode").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>

@Html.DropDownList("MasterId",ViewBag.MasterId as SelectList,"Select Master Code",new { @class = "form-control"})
<select id="Subcode"></select>
```

And code from controller

```cs
public JsonResult FindSubCode(int master_id)
{
    List<string> SubCodeList = new List<string>();
    switch(master_id)
    {
        case 1:
            SubCodeList.Add("Test");
            break;
        case 2:
            SubCodeList.Add("Test2");
            break;
    }
    return Json(SubCodeList);
}
```

Why I'm writing this problem as IIS Configuration, because if I run locally this application, everything works fine. But when I run on server I got error from code "Error in Getting SubCodes!!".

I tried to debug and get next error: [Error when devug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPhtD.png)

Any suggestion how I can fix this ?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with configuration. Verify your URL. `/Audit/FindSubCode` would be pointing to the root of the server which may be a different path to where the application is being served from. Try not to hard code the path but rather use razor to generate the path. ie `@(Url.Action("FindSubCode","Audit")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with configuration. Verify your URL.

`/Audit/FindSubCode` would be pointing to the root of the server which may be a different path to where the application is being served from.

Try not to hard code the path but rather use razor engin `UrlHelper` to generate the path.

```
CountryOptions.url = "@(Url.Action("FindSubCode","Audit")";
```